# Trying to integrate dialogflow and firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I am trying to integrate dialogflow with firebase using Webhook.
The response I receive is:

"webhookStatus": {
    "code": 13,
   "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error."
 }

Webhook is: https://us-central1-miarduino-844c8.cloudfunctions.net/receiveAssistantRequests

Firebase rules are:

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

index.js I have used is:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const DialogflowApp = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;

exports.receiveAssistantRequests = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    const app = new DialogflowApp({ request: request, response: response });

    function handlerRequest(app) {

        const device = app.getArgument('devices');
        const status = app.getArgument('status');

        return admin.database().ref(`/automation/${device}/value`).set(status)
            .then(snapshot => {
                app.ask(`Ok, switching ${device} ${status}. Do you want to control anything else?`);
            });

    }
    app.handleRequest(handlerRequest);
});
```

If I use soapUI for making the request to: https://us-central1-miarduino-844c8.cloudfunctions.net/receiveAssistantRequests
I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Content-Type=text/plain; charset=utf-8

X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff

X-Cloud-Trace-Context=7327cb053558c4598e01b0218e61e5cf;o=1

Date=Thu, 08 Aug 2019 10:19:12 GMT

Server=Google Frontend

Content-Length=36

Alt-Svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"


Error: could not handle the request
```

Has anyone idea regarding how to solve this issue?

Not sure if the issue is located in Dialogflow or in Firebase

Comment: This sounds like there is a problem in your code. You can take a look at the error logs from when it is called by going to console.firebase.google.com, selecting "Functions" on the left, and then "logs" in the top navigation. If you update your question with the contents of the error log, we may be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp({
      databaseURL: "YOUR_DATABASE_URL"});
    process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      const agent = new WebhookClient({request,response});
      console.log('dailog firebase admin'+agent);
      console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
      console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
      }
```